# FusionPBX: How to Provision binary files?

Tags: fusionpbx

I am currently trying to auto-provision a SNOM phone with FusionPBX v4.4. When it comes to provisioning of certificates, SNOM needs these in DER format, which is *binary*.

Provisioning of text files works like a charm by calling `http://fusionpbx.example.com:80/app/provision/?mac=000413xxxxxx&file=mytextfile`

However, if the requested file is binary, the call fails with

> Fatal error:   in
>   /var/www/fusionpbx/resources/templates/engine/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 3

It seems like FusionPBX is trying to parse the file with some template engine. **Is there any chance (like an URL parameter) to disable parsing of the file and just deliver it as is?**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the DER format yet can you provide a link to info on it. So I will have example to test with?

Comment: Essentially, any binary file will do, but you can test it with a real self-signed certificate that can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2w06fx3v9rusez2/testcert.der?dl=0

I put this file to /var/www/fusionpbx/resources/templates/provision/snom/320/testcert.der and try to access it via `curl 'http://fusionpbx.example.com:80/app/provision/?mac=000413xxxxxx&file=testcert.der'`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run a binary through the template engine. Instead just put the file in the web directory and pull the file directly.